# Set SPWeb title on a SharePoint site using PowerShell

Tags: deployment, powershell, language

I'm having problems setting the title of a root web in a site collection when creating it in an other language then English. When i run the script under using 1033, it works fine the site title is set to the input. But then I change to 1044 Norwegian I get no error but the title is empty (I have installed the language package). Here is the script (I'm using a custome site definition, but set it to STS#0 in the example same problem):

```
    Write-Host "******** Create site. ***********" -f Green
    Write-Host "Please enter the URL and the administrator of the site to create" -f Green
    [console]::ForegroundColor = "yellow"
    $newSiteUrl = Read-Host "Please enter the site Url to for the site"
    $siteAdministrator = Read-Host "Please enter the site administrator"
    $webTitle = Read-Host "Please enter the title of the root"
    [console]::ResetColor()


    $site = New-SPSite $newSiteUrl -OwnerAlias $siteAdministrator -Language 1044
    $web = $site.RootWeb 
    $web.ApplyWebTemplate("STS#0")
    $web.Title = $webTitle
    $web.Update()
    Write-Host "The Installation is complete please visit the site at" $web.URL -f Green
```

So how can I set the title of a site using an other language then English?

Comment: Are you using any special characters in the Norwegian title?

Comment: No I@m trying to name it Norge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do it in 2 steps? The [New-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607937.aspx) cmdlet takes a webtemplate and a title parameter too?

Comment: Hi thank you I did not find any parameter called Title. But the -Name parameter worked. The template is a custome one so I have to add i after the web is created. But when using 1033 I do not need to use the -Name parameter the $web.Title works. I will probebly get problems with it if I need to add sub webs.

Comment: -Name is the same as Title

Comment: If the webtemplate is installed, there should be no problem using it. Check `Get-SPWebTemplates | Select Name` and just paste in the Name value. For Custom Web template that would be something like {guid}#YourTemplate

Comment: @Anders I tryed that but never got it to work. But then I found this blog http://mkdot.net/blogs/darko/archive/2011/02/17/create-web-from-custom-template-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx and was able to set the template. But why does not SPWeb.Title work?? Lets say I whant to create a sub site, I can't do that using SPSite?

Comment: Just tryed creating a sub site using New-SPWeb and the -Name parameter worked. Seems like the is somthing strage with the $web.Title and languages.

Comment: @Anders tryed using the {guid}#Template name on New-SPWeb it worked there.

Comment: yep. New-SPWeb -Name should work fine